# Using linux commands in window terminal

Tags: linux

How can I use in the window terminal the linux commands?
For example: use the "ls" command to see the directories of the files inside the same window terminal, if someone knows about it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, depending on what you mean by your request:

You could use *wsl* (windows subsystem for linux) and have fun with the Linux shell inside Windows (It's running a linux distribution however, so I don't know if it's what you want).

I use personally **git bash** and I think that's what you want.

If by "using linux commands" you mean practising with the Linux environment, I strongly suggest to install a VM with Linux on it, or go as far as dual-booting it with Windows.
If you are experienced and you just want a way to have the same commands, then as I said, Git bash or also **Cygwin** are the way to go

Comment: Please don't answer obviously off-topic questions. This has nothing to with programming.

Comment: thank you. I'm new to the stack overflow community and didn't know about it, sorry :) Can you please explain why a linux question is off topic? It could be nice to know how to have linux commands in windows, if you develop on both platforms frequently. Only technical questions are allowed? tools and practical stuff is always off topic? thank you if you reply

Comment: [so] is dedicated to programming problems or things that happen primarily in a programming context. Neither of these apply to the question above.

Comment: More specifically - check bullet point 6: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: P.S.: Also check the hover-help of the Linux-Tag ...